# Setting graphics driver without xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, udev

It looks like X has this new approach of working without a xorg.conf and instead letting udev
do all the configuration. Is there a nice description of this out there?

More specifically I installed nvidia drivers and they created a x-config file. Now if I want
to remove this config file. What to I have to set up in udev to get Xorg automatically choose the nvidia driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xorg only uses udev for input devices.   Graphics device configuration is still handled via `xorg.conf` if the autoconfiguration defaults do not work for you.

Comment: Is there a wiki or something, which explains how to configure input devices with udev? And which options there are for which input device etc.

Comment: @user75250: Yes, see: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Input_device_configuration and http://wiki.debian.org/XStrikeForce/InputHotplugGuide

Answer (score 0):

What distribution are you using? With Debian, for example, you'll have to create an xorg.conf. First do the following:

```
apt-get install module-assistant nvidia-kernel-common

m-a auto-install nvidia-kernel-source
```

Then make an xorg.conf that contains the following:

```
Section "Module"
    Load        "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Video Card"
    Driver      "nvidia"
EndSection
```

You can find more details [here](http://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers).

Comment: Yes such a file was created, when I installed the nvidia. I thought the new way of configuring X was to use udev. But this only works for input devices (see other answer).